# jekyll embed iframe don't work

Tags: html, iframe, jekyll

I search a lot in both google and here in SO, but I did not find the answer.

I use jekyll, and in the about-me page, I what to embed [this](http://music.163.com/#/outchain/2/29750802/) , the given `iframe` looks like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width=298 height=52 src="http://music.163.com/outchain/player?type=2&id=29750802&auto=0&height=32"></iframe>
```

I used it in my about-me page like this:

```
{% raw %}
<iframe frameborder="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width=298 height=52 src="http://music.163.com/outchain/player?type=2&id=29750802&auto=0&height=32"></iframe>
{% endraw %}
```

It looks like all right but it did not work, instead of what I wanted, it shows raw text not the `iframe`.

I have tried nearly everything and still not working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said, I tried everything. And finally when I add double quotes to

```
width=298 height=52
```

like this:

```
width="298" height="52"
```

It finally worked!

I checked on youtube, and I find that youtube did quote the `width` and `height` in the first place. So I think some site may need some kind of change, like the site I used.